# staggeredgridlayoutmanager setspancount is not working in fragement

Tags: android-fragments, gridview, android-recyclerview

i am trying to change the span count by passing a value from activity, the value is passing but the span is not changing , my code is like ,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstance){
        mStaggeredLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_fragment, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mStaggeredLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //Data size is fixed - improves performance
        mAdapter = new TravelListAdapter(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        try{
            int span = getArguments().getInt("grid",0);
            mStaggeredLayoutManager.setSpanCount(span);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(span), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

        return inflatedView;
    }
```

why is it not working?

Comment: I solved the problem , via replacing it from the activity

Answer (score 0):

If you change the span count of the staggered grid layout manager you need to add it to the recycler view again in order to apply the changes. So it's probably better to first pass the span count value and then add the layout manager to the recycler view.